# How to register custom user using pop up in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, popup, woocommerce, registration

I am developing e-commerce website in WordPress. I have added one custom registration form in Content in pop up plugin . I want to validate and submit that form and add user as a my website user. What should i do? how should i submit a form ? I am using WordPress 4.2.

Comment: what do you mean by `as a my website user`?

Comment: it means he/she will be my customer of ecommerce website.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the above code sugggested by **Jitendra**. Put that code in your **functions.php** file in your theme directory.

Wrap that code with a function and in bottom of the function like following

```
    function add_user() {

        $website = "http://example.com";
        $userdata = array(
            'user_login'  =>  $_POST['user'],
            'user_url'    =>  $website,
            'user_pass'   =>  $_POST['pass'],
        );

        $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

        //On success
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
            echo "User created : ". $user_id;
        }

print_r($_POST); die();
    }

add_action('init', 'add_user');
```

Source : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user

Check what does this output

Answer (score 0):

Create your pop up form and on submit. get data in post. and save using below function. it will store new user in yout wp site

Create Your custom form and use `wp_insert_user` function for user registration.

```
<?php

$website = "http://example.com";
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  'login_name',
    'user_url'    =>  $website,
    'user_pass'   =>  $password,
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

//On success
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo "User created : ". $user_id;
}

?>
```

To add a user use ether `wp_insert_user` or wp_create_user.  `wp_create_user` ONLY creates a user, and does not allow for managing any extra user fields. wp_insert_user allows for filling in all user fields.

```
<?php wp_insert_user( $userdata ); ?>
```

Comment: I couldn't got values of form inputs. how can i get a value ? i don't get your answer. how can i implement it in my site. @Jitendra

Comment: so first start learning basic. start with core php. its not platform where i will  make full project for you. its just if you stuck at somewhere.

Comment: i work in core php, bro. but i dont know how to deal with custom form in wordpress. Thats it

Comment: ok then put your code .. or try print_r($_POST); die(); and check what your get.